# SimpleCV console cmd is not working at all in RPI 3B running on Raspbian Buster release

Tags: pi-3, opencv, raspbian-buster

[image: Traceback|SyntaxError]

I have enclosed the screenshot of the error above.

***Looking for solution to SimpleCV traceback/syntax error problem:***

I have already tried installing **SimpleCV** with a **fresh image of Raspbian Buster**.

Also, tried **re-installing SimpleCV** every time, with a **newer python3 version: 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8**.

***But, the error still persists***.

I am using **RPi 3B** running **Raspbian Buster release**.

Using **update-alternatives** I changed **python** and **python3** versions >> **3.5.9**

Similarly, used the same method to change **pip** and **pip3** version >> **20.1**

Also, **edited /usr/bin/lsb_release** from #! /usr/bin/python2.7 to **#! /usr/bin/python3.5**

Then, installed SimpleCV following these lines of code:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ipython python-opencv python-scipy python-numpy python-setuptools python-pip
$ sudo pip install svgwrite
$ https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/zipball/master --no-cache-dir
$ pip install 'IPython==4' --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message, did you try to edit "base. py" and correct the syntax error by adding parantheses to the statement?
... print('unit test')

Answer (score 1):

The `print` statement requires parentheses since Python 3. It looks like you are trying to run Python 2 code with Python 3. Try running it with Python 2 or see if you can find an updated version.